# Html password box, if correct, fade in to reveal the blog

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, passwords

So I've managed to make a password redirect page, as in when the **correct password is entered, the page redirects you to another url.** (psswrdtest.tumblr.com and the password is correctpsswrd, which redirects you to google.com*)

It works fine and all, and yesterday I proceeded to try and make the **password page** **fade in** **to reveal the blog** (if the **correct password** is entered.) I inserted my password code into my current theme and used a bit of jquery, but it still won't work!! This is my most recent attempt.

Any idea of what i'm doing wrong?

This is the css:

```
#hamuko {
    position:fixed;
    display:table;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background:{color:background}
    url('{image:background}') left bottom repeat;
    {block:iflittlecursor} cursor: url(http://i.imgur.com/ZOrzC.png), auto; {/block:iflittlecursor}
    z-index:2147483647;
    top:0;
}

#hamuko #aki {
    display:table-cell;
    font-size:16px;
    vertical-align:middle;
    text-align:center;
    {block:iflittlecursor}cursor: url(http://i.imgur.com/ZOrzC.png), auto; {/block:iflittlecursor}
}

#hamuko #sooj {
    margin-top:{text:top}px;
    margin-left:{text:text left}px;
    margin-bottom:5px;
    width:{text:text width};
    text-align:center;
    color: {color:text};
}

#hamuko #yosugay {
    border:1px solid {color:border};
    width:150px;
    height:25px;
    font-size:19px;
    line-height:19px;
    background:{color:form background};
    color:{color:border};
}

#hamuko #stupei {
    z-index:1;
    position:absolute;
    margin-left:155px;
    {block:iflittlecursor}cursor: url(http://i.imgur.com/ZOrzC.png), auto; {/block:iflittlecursor}
}

#hamuko #button {
    margin-left:5px;
    border:1px solid {color:border};
    background:{color:form background};
    width:40px;
    height:29px;
    text-align:center;
    color:{color:border};
}

#hamuko #yosugay:hover {
    {block:iflittlecursor}cursor:url(http://i.imgur.com/ZOrzC.png), auto;{/block:iflittlecursor}
}

#hamuko #kouchan {
    position:absolute;
    margin-top:{text:pic up}px;
    margin-left:{text:pic left}px;
    width:{text:pic width};
    z-index:0;
}
```

This is my jquery, pasted right after the css codes for it,

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
function goForit() {
    var passwd;
    passwd = document.getElementById('yosugay').value;
    if(passwd=="{text:password}"){
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#hamuko').fadeOut(1000);
        });
    else{
        alert('{text:wrong alert}');
    }
}
</SCRIPT>
```

This is the html that P added

```
<body>
<div id="hamuko">
    <div id="sooj">
        <img src="{image:pixel}" />
        {text:form text}
        <img src="{image:pixel}" />
    </div>
    <div id="aki">
        <form>
            <input type="password" name="arisatos" id="yosugay">
        </form>
    </div>
    <div id="stupei">
        <form>
            <button id="button" type="button" onClick="goForit()">{text:button text}</button>
        </form> 
    </div>
    <img id="kouchan" src="{image:pic}" title="{text:pic title}">
</div>
```

But the results are

- My password code won't show up
- In fact, it went from (http://psswrdtest.tumblr.com/), where my password code is working fine to (/http://yamagitenshi.tumblr.com/), where I attempted to make the password page to **fade in** to the blog if the password is correct (correctpsswrd)
- Where a useless blank white box stays on the page
- For anyone who wants to see the full code of the failed attempt, view the source of http://yamagitenshi.tumblr.com

Please, does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? I thought I did fine and have checked multiple times and even changed the format of my css (etc from #hamuko #aki to .hamuko #aki or #hamuko .aki and even #hamuko-content #aki), but to no avail!!

Thank you so,so much to anyone who could point out what I did wrong, and even if you don't.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `.click()` instead of inline `onClick` function and replace all your current javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function() {
        $('#button').click(function() {
            var passwd = document.getElementById('yosugay').value;
            if(passwd=="{text:password}"){
                $('#hamuko').fadeOut(1000);
            } else {
                alert('{text:wrong alert}');
            }
         });
     });
</script>
```